# How to make a JavaFX 3D Box transparent

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, transparency

I am trying to make the 3D `Box` to be transparent that I can see through. I am using the following code to make it.

```java
Box truck = new Box(Truck.WIDTH, Truck.HEIGHT, Truck.DEPTH);
truck.setTranslateX(Truck.WIDTH >> 1);
truck.setTranslateY(Truck.HEIGHT >> 1);
truck.setTranslateZ(Truck.DEPTH >> 1);
truckMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.SILVER.deriveColor(.3, .3, 0.4, .3));
truck.setMaterial(truckMaterial);

group = new Group();
group.getChildren().add(truck);

mainScene = new SubScene(group, SCREEN_WIDTH * .75, SCREEN_HEIGHT, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
mainScene.setFill(Color.SILVER);

// set up the camera
Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
camera.translateXProperty().set(Truck.WIDTH - ((mainScene.getWidth() / 2) + (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2)));
camera.translateYProperty().set(Truck.HEIGHT - (mainScene.getHeight() / 2));
camera.translateZProperty().set(-(Truck.DEPTH / 0.2));
mainScene.setCamera(camera);
```

This line `truckMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.SILVER.deriveColor(.3, .3, 0.4, .3));` supposed to make it transparent. The material is `truckMaterial = new PhongMaterial();`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A related example is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298705/230513).

Comment: I got the expected result using variations of your color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the opacity of the `diffuseMaterial` to a non-opaque color. Set the opacity of the color below 1, and the material will become translucent.

I know you have done that in your example, but you have a silver translucent object painted on a silver background, so you aren't going to see much.  Also, `.3` on opacity for certain colors will still be pretty opaque, so you might not see much through it.
 
As noted in:

- [JavaFX 3D Transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308397/javafx-3d-transparency)

> There's no depth sort algorithm though, meaning that order of how 3D shapes are added to the scene *matters*.

So, if we take the 3D orbiter example from here:

- [How can I make a node rotate around a circle using the path transition method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730183/how-can-i-make-a-node-rotate-around-a-circle-using-the-path-transition-method/77731026#77731026)

And modify the group order from:

```
Group space = new Group(sun, sunsRadiance, orbit, earth);
```

to:

```
Group space = new Group(earth, orbit, sun, sunsRadiance);
```

And change the `diffuseColor` of the Sun to an opacity of `.1`.

```
sun.setMaterial(
        new PhongMaterial(
                Color.ORANGERED
                        .deriveColor(
                                0,
                                1,
                                1,
                                .1
                        ),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                illuminationMap
        )
);
```

Then you will see the earth brightly lit in daytime as it passes behind the translucent sun.

[image: front]
[image: side]
[image: back]