# JavaFX_2D Animation_How to make a circle rotating other circle which is also rotating

Tags: java, animation, javafx, 2d

I just want to make a 2D animation that the moon rotating the earth rotating the sun.
I could see some solar system codes but they are too complex and hard to read for me.
Could anyone help me with this.

An easy and simple JavaFX 2D animation code that make
an object rotating another object which is also rotating another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adaption of the answer to:

- [How can I make a node rotate around a circle using the path transition method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730183/how-can-i-make-a-node-rotate-around-a-circle-using-the-path-transition-method/77731026#77731026)

The earth from the answer referenced above is replaced with an earth system.  The earth system is comprised of the earth, the moon and a lunar orbit path.  The earth system is stored in a `Group`.

A transparent background of the total size of the earth system (lunar orbit + moon width) is added to the earth system so that the earth system remains a constant size as the moon orbits the earth.

The earth system is set to orbit the sun.  And the moon is set to orbit the earth.

[image: solar system]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SolApp extends Application {
    private static final double
            S = 400,             // extent of the solar system
            C = S / 2,           // center of the solar system
            SR = S / 10, ER = S / 40, LR = S / 80, // sun/earth/moon radius
            O = S * 3/8, LO = S / 20, // earth/moon orbit radius
            ES = (LO + LR) * 2,  // extent of the earth system
            EC = ES / 2;         // center of the earth system
    private static final Duration T = Duration.seconds(15);
    private static final Color INDIA_INK = Color.web("#3c3f4a");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle sun = new Circle(
                C, C,
                SR,
                Color.ORANGERED
        );

        Circle earth = new Circle(
                EC, EC,
                ER,
                Color.PALETURQUOISE
        );

        Circle moon = new Circle(
                EC + LO, EC,
                LR,
                Color.SILVER
        );

        Circle lunarOrbit = new Circle(EC, EC, LO);
        lunarOrbit.setFill(null);
        lunarOrbit.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
        lunarOrbit.setStrokeWidth(1);

        Circle earthOrbit = new Circle(C, C, O);
        earthOrbit.setFill(null);
        earthOrbit.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        earthOrbit.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle earthSystemExtent = new Rectangle(ES, ES, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Group earthSystem = new Group(earthSystemExtent, earth, lunarOrbit, moon);
        earthSystem.setTranslateX(C + O - EC);
        earthSystem.setTranslateY(C - EC);

        Pane solarSystem = new Pane(sun, earthOrbit, earthSystem);
        solarSystem.setPrefSize(S, S);
        solarSystem.setBackground(Background.fill(INDIA_INK));

        Animation earthOrbiter = getPathTransitionOrbiter(
                lunarOrbit,
                moon
        );
        earthOrbiter.setRate(12);

        Animation solarOrbiter = getPathTransitionOrbiter(
                earthOrbit,
                earthSystem
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(solarSystem));
        stage.show();

        solarOrbiter.play();
        earthOrbiter.play();
    }

    private static Transition getPathTransitionOrbiter(
            Circle orbit,
            Node satellite
    ) {
        PathTransition orbiter = new PathTransition(T, orbit, satellite);
        
        orbiter.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        orbiter.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        
        return orbiter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much 'jewelsea'. This was my first Stackoverflow question and the answer was exactly what I wanted to do. I really appreciate it.